# Android: How to open a specific folder?

Tags: java, android, directory

I have an audio recording app that has a button that sholud open the folder containing the recorded audio files, but it only opens "Downloads" folder even though I never specified it. Some implementations I found only work for certain file explorer. Opening with default file explorer would be perfect for me. Please help with any implementation that allows opening of a specified folder, whether public or private directory.

My code (using android version 11) throws error :`Error opening file`

```
private void createMyfolder(){
    String folderName = "MyFolder"; // Change this to your desired folder name
    File subdirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), folderName);

    if (!subdirectory.exists()) {
        if (subdirectory.mkdirs()) {
            // Parent directory created successfully

            Toast.makeText(this, "Subdirectory does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the directory creation failed
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create subdirectory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Subdirectory exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri folderUri = Uri.parse("file://" + subdirectory);
      //Uri folderUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.android.sun2meg.audiorecorder.fileprovider", subdirectory);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(folderUri, "*/*");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                // No app available to handle the Intent, show a message to the user
                Toast.makeText(this, "No app available to open .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Handle the case where no app can open the file type
            Toast.makeText(this, "No app can open this file type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle other exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error opening file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
//            startActivity(intent);
    }


<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

android:authorities="com.android.sun2meg.audiorecorder.fileprovider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">

Comment: `public or private directory. Thanks in advance.` An Android file chooser wil never display files from apps private storage. Also you better do not thank in advance as we expect thanks afterwards.

Comment: ACTION_VIEW does not open in a folder. It is no file chooser either.

Comment: ACTION_,GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT have extra INITIAL_URI. Why dit you comment it?

Comment: AVTION_VIEW with FileProvider has nothing to do with your question. So please remove.

Comment: You also did not tell us who displayed that error or which statement caused it.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your contribution. I've tried many options so I just comment them out to try others.the error is caught from the last catch block of the code.

Comment: That is your your own error message. You should display the exception message instead.

Comment: Edit your post. Ask about ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_VIEW. Not both. Confusing nie.

Comment: @blackapps ok thanks.i have come to realise that android security restrictions won't allow for such.